# cannot map host port to docker with port mapping

Tags: docker

I am launching a docker container as follows:

```
docker run -p 5001:5001 -it --mount type=bind,src=/datasets/,target=/data 5adc0de90a81 bash
```

I have verified that on my host machine, this port is active. So doing `curl localhost:5001`gives me a valid output.

Doing the same inside the container results in:

```
url: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5001: Connection refused
```

I am running osx 12.6 with docker version `20.10.12`. I have tried putting the port mapping at different places but does not seem to help.

Comment: For referencing services running within docker from within docker node itself you should use  "host.docker.internal" so host.docker.internal:5001. More about this here : https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

Comment: Still getting connection refused for some reason.

Comment: Ok, using that along with --net="host" seems to work. I am not sure why the publishing is not enough...

Comment: Because docker container networks are isolated. Each container has its own network. If you want to access the host network from within the container, then you have to use the `--net=host`.

Comment: But none of the examples on the docker website mention that. If I am explicitly publishing the port, why do I have to do this.

Comment: Connecting to a port inside the container from the container itself does not need any port mapping and has nothing to do with it. What is the software running inside that container? My guess: your service listens on the container IP (the one used by port mapping when connection from your own host) but not on 127.0.0.1 inside the container. An easy confirmation is to get your container IP (for example with `docker inspect <your_container> | jq -r '.[].NetworkSettings.Networks[].IPAddress'`) and use it to test a connection from inside your container.